# Broadcast receiver stops registering broadcasts after a few seconds

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    startService(new Intent(this, jam_service.class));
    super.onStart();
```

As soon as I create my main activity, I start my service that looks like this

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(myBroadcastReceiver.BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED);
   IntentFilter(myBroadcastReceiver.BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Which registers this broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    c.writeNewUser(intent.getStringExtra("track"),"user", intent.getStringExtra("track"));
```

The broadcast receiver detects when the user changes songs in Spotify, and it works sometimes for a short period of time after launching my app and then switching to Spotify, or when my app is open and changing Spotify songs from the notification bar. I want this receiver to never stop listening to broadcasts, even after my app has been in the background for a while. Why does it stop working?

Comment: you are registering receiver inside Service?

Comment: @Augusto yep, the receiver is being created within the service, which is created as soon as onCreate in the main activity is run.

Comment: The services restart every time that you close the app, apparentely your problem is that.

Comment: @Augusto I see. Where do you recommend that I register the service then?